# CSS box-shadow did not work at IE or Safari

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, safari

```
#keyboard {
position: fixed;
background: #eee;
display: none;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius:7px;
width: 950px;
height: 300px;
padding: 5px;
cursor: move;
background-image:url('BackgroundImage.jpg');
box-shadow: -5px -5px 5px 5px #888; 
-moz-border-radius: -5px -5px 5px 5px #888;
-webkit-border-radius: -5px -5px 5px 5px #888;
```

}

At upper css code, it is okey at Firfox browser.
But I cannot display shadow at IE8 or IE6 and safari as well.

```
box-shadow: -5px -5px 5px 5px #888;
```

Please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To offer IE users an effect similar to box-shadow, I usually make use of proprietary MS filters, the following is an extract from my css:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 4px 19px #333333;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 4px 19px #333333;
box-shadow: 2px 4px 19px #333333;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=6, Direction=115, Color='#333333')";
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=6, Direction=115, Color='#333333');
```

Obviously the effect on IE is different, but playing with the various parameters you can get very closer (or at least acceptable) to your expectation on every browser

Answer (score 1):

Box shadow which is css3, not supported in ie8 and older browser, But still we can get this using [css3pie](http://css3pie.com) script

Answer (score 0):

Also try prefixr.com, it helps me a lot for making css3 browser compatible